# How to download the content of the web page to Google sheet, using importxml

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to download the contents of a query from the following webpage

https://registro.br/tecnologia/ferramentas/whois/?search=plasticosduvale.com.br

I've tried for hours using `importxml`, but I can not download the correct block of information `"class =" whois-content "`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://registro.br/tecnologia/ferramentas/whois/?search=plasticosduvale.com.br";"//class[@name='whois-content']/content")
```

I hope to get the whole block of information

Comment: "https://registro.br/tecnologia/tools/whois/?search=plasticosduvale.com.br" returns 'page not found' - might explain why it didn't work?

Comment: Hi Thank you. 
The correct link is

https://registro.br/tecnologia/ferramentas/whois/?search=plasticosduvale.com.br